# ZF 1: How to set up Zend_Mail Transport into code

Tags: zend-framework, zend-mail

I was wondering if there anyway to move this configuration from the INI into the bootstrap.php in a way it would be the default globally. If so, how should I do it? I'm with zend 1.11.

thanks in advance.

```
;resources.mail.transport.type = smtp
;resources.mail.transport.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
;resources.mail.transport.auth = login
;resources.mail.transport.ssl = ssl
;resources.mail.transport.port = 465
;resources.mail.transport.username = email@example.com
;resources.mail.transport.password = pass
;resources.mail.transport.register = true ; True by default
;resources.mail.defaultFrom.email = email@example.com
;resources.mail.defaultFrom.name = "Foo"
;resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.email = email@example.com
;resources.mail.defaultReplyTo.name = "Foo"
```

[SOLUTION]

Actually it worked for me adding:

```
        $config = array(
            'ssl' => $transport_ssl,
            'port' => $transport_port,
            'auth' => $transport_auth,
            'username' => $transport_username,
            'password' => $transport_password,
            'register' => $transport_register,
        );

        $transport = new \Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($transport_host, $config);
//        var_dump($transport);exit;
        \Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($transport);
```